# NgbDropdown keep refreshing class 'dropdown' and 'open'

Tags: angular, dropdown, ng-bootstrap

I'm using @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap in my Angular 12 application, and I'm using NgbDropdown to display some dropdown.
When the dropdown is open, the classed are always refreshing and this making the dropdown to be slower and in bad performance.

See the element that is being watched all the time until I close the dropdown.
Is there a way to make the performance of this dropdown better? or should I replace a dropdown library?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and what led me down the right path was [this](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/3199)  answer from the ng-bootstrap guys:

> It is true that out positioning is an expansive task, but there should not be so many change detection cycles triggered, this is a more general concern for and Angular application.

This means that a good solution to the problem (which will improve the application whether you use the dropdown or not) is to find out what causes so many change detection cycles in the first place.

In order to do that, I added the following code to one of the components in the page containing the dropdown:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.ngZone.onStable.subscribe(() => {
        console.log('on stable was called');
    });
}
```

Then you can actually see in the console that there are too many change detection cycles, but more importantly, you can put a breakpoint there, and look at the call-stack to find out what initiated those cycles. In my case it was a 3rd party for resize-observer which we used, and switching to native ResizeObserver (or polyfill) solved the problem.